# DOMLSSerializer : Cannot print big document

Tags: c++, xml, xerces-c

I'm using DOMLSSerialize with a DOMLSOutput to print a DOMDocument to an xml file. I need to print a rather large quantity of xml (between 10-20Mb).

I run into a problem when I try to print a document document bigger than ~6Mb. The xml file only contains ~6Mo, it get crop at 6Mo the closing tags are not in the document.

I understand that using a DOMLSSerializer and a DOMDocument implies that the document is printed all at once. Thus, i'm mostly sure that my problem is due to a buffer that is too small somewhere in the DOMLSSerializer, the DOMDocument or the DOMLSOutput... However, I don't know where the buffer is and how to make it bigger.

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
DOMImplementation *pImplement = DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(L"LS");
xercesc::DOMLSSerializer* _pSerializer = ((DOMImplementationLS*)pImplement)->createLSSerializer();

XMLFormatTarget *formatTarget = new LocalFileFormatTarget("Debug.xml");
xercesc::DOMLSOutput* _output = ((DOMImplementationLS*)pImplement)->createLSOutput();
_output->setByteStream(formatTarget);

//later
_pSerializer->write(pmyDOMDocument, _output);
_pDOMDocument->release();
```

Comment: Just a sketch. write() takes a DOMNode as input. Hence it could print a DOMElement and its subtree. Maybe you need `conf->setParameter (XMLUni::fgDOMXMLDeclaration, false);` as done in the file [serializer.cxx from CodeSynthesis XSD](http://scm.codesynthesis.com/?p=xsd/xsd.git;a=blob;f=examples/cxx/tree/streaming/serializer.cxx;hb=HEAD)

Comment: Oh, that's a good lead. I thought about writing the part of the dom every time, but the XmlDeclaration was always in the way. Thanks !